# Hiding Panel - by default is open when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

The issue is when the page loads, by default the panel at the bottom of the page is open. I need to set when the page loads the panel should be closed and the functioning will remain same as in current, that when we click the panel opens and again clicked the panel will be closed or vice-versa.

```js
(function($) {

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    Panel.init();

    $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller', function() {
      Panel.togglePanel();
    });

  });

  var Panel = {

    isVisible: true,
    showMessage: null,
    hideMessage: null,
    animationDuration: 650,
    animationEasing: 'linear',

    init: function() {

    },

    hidePanel: function() {
      $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
        bottom: -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
      }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
        Panel.isVisible = false;
        Panel.updateTabMessage();
      });
    },

    showPanel: function() {
      $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
        bottom: 0
      }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
        Panel.isVisible = true;
        Panel.updateTabMessage();
      });
    },

    togglePanel: function() {
      ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
    },

    updateTabMessage: function() {
      if (this.isVisible) {
        $('.tab-controller .close').show();
        $('.tab-controller .show').hide();
      } else {
        $('.tab-controller .close').hide();
        $('.tab-controller .show').show();
      }
    },

    getAnimationOffset: function() {
      return $('.panel-content').height();
    }

  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.panel-wrapper * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.panel-controller {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.tab-controller {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px;
  background-color: #8C293B;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
.tab-controller * {
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-controller .show {
  display: none;
}
.panel-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8C293B;
}
.panel-content .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 98%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <div class="panel-controller">
    <div class="tab-controller">
      <span class="close">CLOSE PANEL</span>
      <span class="show">OPEN PANEL</span>
    </div>
    <!-- tab-controller -->
  </div>
  <!-- panel-controller -->
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="content clearfix">
      <div>This
        <br/>Space
        <br/>is
        <br/>inside
        <br/>panel.</div>
    </div>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <!-- panel-content -->
</div>
<!-- panel-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css start off by hiding ".close" instead of ".show".

Now in your init function, set the css bottom attr of your panel wrapper.

Done. =)

Now your panel is closed on load and your logic is intact =)

```js
(function($) {

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    Panel.init();

    $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller', function() {
      Panel.togglePanel();
    });

  });

  var Panel = {

    isVisible: false,
    showMessage: null,
    hideMessage: null,
    animationDuration: 650,
    animationEasing: 'linear',

    init: function() {
        $('.panel-wrapper').css("bottom", -(Panel.getAnimationOffset()));
    },

    hidePanel: function() {
      $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
        bottom: -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
      }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
        Panel.isVisible = false;
        Panel.updateTabMessage();
      });
    },

    showPanel: function() {
      $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
        bottom: 0
      }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
        Panel.isVisible = true;
        Panel.updateTabMessage();
      });
    },

    togglePanel: function() {
      ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
    },

    updateTabMessage: function() {
      if (this.isVisible) {
        $('.tab-controller .close').show();
        $('.tab-controller .show').hide();
      } else {
        $('.tab-controller .close').hide();
        $('.tab-controller .show').show();
      }
    },

    getAnimationOffset: function() {
      return $('.panel-content').height();
    }

  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.panel-wrapper * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.panel-controller {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.tab-controller {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px;
  background-color: #8C293B;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
.tab-controller * {
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-controller .close {
  display: none;
}
.panel-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8C293B;
}
.panel-content .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 98%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <div class="panel-controller">
    <div class="tab-controller">
      <span class="close">CLOSE PANEL</span>
      <span class="show">OPEN PANEL</span>
    </div>
    <!-- tab-controller -->
  </div>
  <!-- panel-controller -->
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="content clearfix">
      <div>This
        <br/>Space
        <br/>is
        <br/>inside
        <br/>panel.</div>
    </div>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <!-- panel-content -->
</div>
<!-- panel-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Still having a issue while you changed the behavior of the panel to be closed at the time of the loading/initializing but while embedding into the web page it flickers so much as when it loads, at first the panel is seen as open, and then quickly closes the panel without animation. 
This is not I am asking. Can you please change something to improve that it should no flicker while loading webpage and the panel should be closed at the beginning i.e. while loading webpage

Comment: Hi, you should add bottom: -100px; to the "panel-wrapper" class in your css, to ensure that the panel stays outside the screen until initializing it. I edited my answer accordingly. =)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can do two things.

```
 var Panel = {
    isVisible: true,
    showMessage: null,
    hideMessage: null,
    animationDuration: 650,
    animationEasing: 'linear',
    init: function() {
    },
```

first try setting `isVisible: false` that should set the visibility as hidden on load.
If this is not working you can revert the first edit and add in your init function

```
 var Panel = {
    isVisible: true,
    showMessage: null,
    hideMessage: null,
    animationDuration: 650,
    animationEasing: 'linear',
    init: function() {
        Panel.hidePanel();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      
          (function($) {
      
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      
              Panel.init();
      
              $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller', function() {
 
  if( $(".panel-content").hasClass('hidden'))
  {
      $(".panel-content").removeClass('hidden').addClass('open');
      $(".tab-controller .show").css('display','none');
  $(".tab-controller .close").css('display','block');
  } else {  $(".panel-content").removeClass('open').addClass('hidden');
      $(".tab-controller .show").css('display','block');
  $(".tab-controller .close").css('display','none'); }
   
             
              });
      
            });
      
            var Panel = {
      
              isVisible: true,
              showMessage: null,
              hideMessage: null,
              animationDuration: 650,
              animationEasing: 'linear',
      
              init: function() {
      
              },
      
              hidePanel: function() {
                $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
                  bottom: -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
                }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
                  Panel.isVisible = false;
                  Panel.updateTabMessage();
                });
              },
      
              showPanel: function() {
                $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
                  bottom: 0
                }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
                  Panel.isVisible = true;
                  Panel.updateTabMessage();
                });
              },
      
              togglePanel: function() {
                ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
              },
      
              updateTabMessage: function() {
                if (this.isVisible) {
                  $('.tab-controller .close').show();
                  $('.tab-controller .show').hide();
                } else {
                  $('.tab-controller .close').hide();
                  $('.tab-controller .show').show();
                }
              },
      
              getAnimationOffset: function() {
                return $('.panel-content').height();
              }
      
            }
          })(jQuery);
      
      
      
          .panel-wrapper * {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
          }
          .panel-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: sans-serif;
          }
          .panel-controller {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
          }
          .tab-controller {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 50px;
            padding: 10px 10px 5px;
            background-color: #8C293B;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
            border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
          }
          .tab-controller * {
            display: block;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
          }
          .tab-controller .close{
            display: none;
          }
          .panel-content {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #8C293B;
          }
          .panel-content .content {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 900px;
            width: 98%;
          }
      
      .hidden
      {
      display:none;
      }
  
   .open
      {
      display:block;
      }
      
      
      
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <div class="panel-wrapper">
            <div class="panel-controller">
              <div class="tab-controller">
                <span class="close">CLOSE PANEL</span>
                <span class="show">OPEN PANEL</span>
              </div>
              <!-- tab-controller -->
            </div>
            <!-- panel-controller -->
            <div class="panel-content hidden">
              <div class="content clearfix">
                <div>This
                  <br/>Space
                  <br/>is
                  <br/>inside
                  <br/>panel.</div>
              </div>
              <!-- content -->
            </div>
            <!-- panel-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- panel-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In page load you can call `hidePanel() function` it will work.

```js
(function($) {

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    Panel.init();


    $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller', function() {
      Panel.togglePanel();

    });

  });

  var Panel = {

    isVisible: true,
    showMessage: null,
    hideMessage: null,
    animationDuration: 650,
    animationEasing: 'linear',

    init: function() {

/*add this code*/

  $('.panel-wrapper').css("bottom", -$('.panel-content').height() + 'px');
    $(".close").css("display", "none");
    $(".show").css("display", "inline");

    },

    hidePanel: function() {
      $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
        bottom: -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
      }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
        Panel.isVisible = false;
        Panel.updateTabMessage();
      });
    },

    showPanel: function() {
      $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
        bottom: 0
      }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
        Panel.isVisible = true;
        Panel.updateTabMessage();
      });
    },

    togglePanel: function() {
      ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
    },

    updateTabMessage: function() {
      if (this.isVisible) {
        $('.tab-controller .close').show();
        $('.tab-controller .show').hide();
      } else {
        $('.tab-controller .close').hide();
        $('.tab-controller .show').show();
      }
    },

    getAnimationOffset: function() {
      return $('.panel-content').height();
    }

  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.panel-wrapper * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.panel-controller {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.tab-controller {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px;
  background-color: #8C293B;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
.tab-controller * {
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-controller .show {
  display: none;
}
.panel-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8C293B;
}
.panel-content .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 98%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <div class="panel-controller">
    <div class="tab-controller">
      <span class="close">CLOSE PANEL</span>
      <span class="show">OPEN PANEL</span>
    </div>
    <!-- tab-controller -->
  </div>
  <!-- panel-controller -->
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="content clearfix">
      <div>This
        <br/>Space
        <br/>is
        <br/>inside
        <br/>panel.</div>
    </div>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <!-- panel-content -->
</div>
<!-- panel-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Still having a issue while you changed the behavior of the panel to be closed at the time of the loading/initializing but while embedding into the web page it flickers so much as when it loads, at first the panel is seen as open, and then quickly closes the panel with animation. This is not I am asking. Can you please change something to improve that it should not flicker while loading webpage and the panel should be closed at the beginning i.e. while loading webpage

Comment: I have edited my answer please check it. may be it is useful.

Comment: Have you clicked the panel for the first time when it loads. It takes two clicks to open panel for the first time. will give an negative impact on visitors

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
init: function() {

},
```

to this:

```
init: function () {
    $('.panel-wrapper').css("bottom", -$('.panel-content').height() + 'px');
    $(".close").css("display", "none");
    $(".show").css("display", "inline");
},
```

Change this:

```
isVisible: true,
```

to this:

```
isVisible: false,
```

Move `Panel.init();` right before `})(jQuery);`

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sgcoqr21/)

Comment: Still having a issue while you changed the behavior of the panel to be closed at the time of the loading/initializing but while embedding into the web page it flickers so much as when it loads, at first the panel is seen as open, and then quickly closes the panel without animation. This is not I am asking. Can you please change something to improve that it should no flicker while loading webpage and the panel should be closed at the beginning i.e. while loading webpage

Comment: Hi, it should be bottom: -100px; , to ensure the panel is outside the screen before initializing it. =)